# Can we open web sites from a chrome app?

Tags: client-server, google-chrome-app

I was just trying to build a chrome app to connect to my local server when it is launched. I added the html "a" tag to the index.html but when i click it nothing happens. I tried changing it to a `<a href="http://www.google.com">` just to see if it works but nothing happened. So, my question is can we make a chrome app to just connect to a server and display the web pages it serves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps cannot simply display remote content in place of local app pages. Your `<a>` tag tries to navigate the *current* page to a remote content, which gets blocked.

You have 2 (well, 3) possibilities, depending on your needs.

1. You can open the link in the system's default browser (which may or may not be Chrome) with `<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">`
2. You can embed a webpage with the [`<webview>` tag](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview), kind of like an iframe.
3. From Chrome 42 (currently Beta), there will be a [`chrome.browser.openTab()`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/browser) function to open something specifically in Chrome.